# Ansible: Set Space Efficiency in a vSAN VMware cluster

Tags: ansible, vmware, vsan

How to set the Space Efficiency in a vSAN cluster with Ansible?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often modules like [`vmware_cluster_vsan` module – Manages virtual storage area network (vSAN) configuration on VMware vSphere clusters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_cluster_vsan_module.html) are just wrapper for the respective REST API. So also [`vmware_cluster_vsan.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vmware_cluster_vsan.py) as [`pyVMomi`](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/tree/master/pyVmomi) and vSAN Management SDK for Python are requrired for the module to work.

> ***How to set the Space Efficiency in a vSAN cluster with Ansible?***

In order to do so, you could

- either review the mentioned module code and enhance it with necessary functionality
- or utilize the [vSAN Management API](https://developer.vmware.com/apis) directly, see also [Using VMware HTTP API using Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/scenario_vmware_http.html)
- or [develop an own Custom Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html), maybe utilizing some of [the vSphere Automation Python SDK samples that use the vSphere Automation python client library](https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python)